# SF2 Sylius: post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

Tags: composer-php, sylius, symfony-2.4

I try to install sylius project with the command:

```
composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard
```

But always have the same error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                       
  The class sylius.model.promotion_subject.class does not exists.

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

In SyliusPromotionBundle, I noticed:

```
       $interfaces = array(
        'Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\PromotionInterface'        =>     'sylius.model.promotion.class',
        'Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\CouponInterface'           => 'sylius.model.promotion_coupon.class',
        'Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\RuleInterface'             => 'sylius.model.promotion_rule.class',
        'Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\ActionInterface'           => 'sylius.model.promotion_action.class',
        'Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\PromotionSubjectInterface' => 'sylius.model.promotion_subject.class',
    );
```

So, I tried to directly add in app/parameters.yml:

```
sylius.model.promotion_subject.class: "Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Model\PromotionSubjectInterface"
```

It seems to work, but I have the feeling it's an ugly solution...

Now: app/console sylius:install leads to:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:phpcr:repository" namespace.
```

Has anybody else encountered the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found strange that we have to do some operations not mentionned in the documentation. I tried again today to install the sylius project from the beginning, and everything seems fine.
As mentionned on the sylius website:
"Sylius is in the pre-alpha development stage."
I guess the team made some changes. Timon, I hope you could be successful with your installation today...
Best Regards.